# In which cities do the following puns apply?

Tags: wordplay, geography

Each of the following phrases refers to a specific city on Earth. You'll find out what I mean when you get the answers.

## In which city...

1. ...is there a giant blockade to prevent small rodents from flooding a river?
2. ...can a 30-year-old male get his skin irradiated while wearing a baseball cap?
3. ...does the phrase "my friend" get translated into two different languages at once?
4. ...is a hole in your skin that sweats considered a piece of music?
5. ...does everyone dress like a superhero, a vampire, or a witch?
6. ...do sounds quickly become more intense by a factor of 10?
7. ...are all the sharp blades plated with gold, or at least something of that colour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cities are:

1. > Amsterdam ((h)amster + dam)
2. > Manhattan (man (in a) hat (gets a) tan)
3. > Miami (mi + ami; mi=spanish for my, ami=french for friend)
4. > Singapore (sing a pore)
5. > Cape Town (legislative capital of South Africa; superheros, vampires and witches all wear capes)
6. > Belfast (bel = factor of ten on log scale for sound level)
7. > Yellowknife (capital of Northwest Territories, Canada)

Comment: That was super-quick. I am guessing 5 has a "wear" and/or "all" in it. Like Allahabad India. (All-aha-bad)

Comment: @kanchirk - I had some help :-) It's a pity there's no city named Halloween.

Comment: Ooh, that 5th one is going to be tricky if that's your line of thinking.

Comment: Yep, Cape Town is right. Answer accepted.

Comment: @JoeZ. - Nice puzzle. I should have got number five first given that I used to live there!

Comment: @Marconius or maybe because you lived there that's why you didn't get it... you didn't see any of those while living there!  :)

Comment: My first answer to number 1 was "Rotterdam", because "rotter" is Danish/Norwegian for rats.

Comment: @Nelson - that was one of the trickier clues! Cape Canaveral might have been acceptable too.

Comment: @kasperd - That's very close. Rats are, however, classified as medium-sized rodents. Interesting that two potential answers to the same clue are both in the same country. On the other hand, the Dutch are masters at controlling water.