# In which U.S. cities do the following puns apply?

Tags: wordplay, geography

It's [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22386/in-which-cities-do-the-following-puns-apply) again, but this time I've decided to focus on cities in the United States of America.

## In which U.S. city...

1. ...is everyone a young male?
2. ...are there red sticks everywhere?
3. ...is everybody actually from a completely unrelated Canadian province?
4. ...does everybody know how long they've been moored?
5. ...does the voltage never vary in their huge industrial laundromats?
6. ...are all the small mountains lent out from other places?
7. ...is every day the Fourth of July?
8. ...is everyone always getting more of something?
9. ...is the fourteenth letter always really nervous?
10. ...do all the people like to make scenes of themselves in their state's Capitol building, or at least sorta sound like they do?

Note that all the cities I'm thinking of have a population greater than 50,000.

Comment: City puns have their limits, Juneau?

Comment: @WBT I know a girl who loves these kinds of puns; Alaska what she thinks.

Comment: Fort what it's Worth, be careful: if you wind up giving her too many bad ones, dat'll be Dallas time you see her!

Comment: If you liked this puzzle, you may also like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33133/13535).

Comment: As feedback to help with the [Canadian version under development](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33133/in-which-us-city-would-you-find-the-following/33136?noredirect=1#comment99624_33136): 2, 7, and 8 were the weakest elements in this set (IMHO).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

...is everyone a young male?

> Boise, ID
>  Young males = Boys = Bois (Thanks, [WBT](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33051/20151))

...are there red sticks everywhere?

> Baton Rouge, LA
>  Baton = stick, Rouge = red

...is everybody actually from a completely unrelated Canadian province?

> New Brunswick, NJ or Ontario, CA
>  Also a Canadian province

...does everybody know how long they've been moored?

> Anchorage, AK
>  moored = anchored, how long = age

...does the voltage never vary in their huge industrial laundromats?

> Washington, D.C.
>  voltage never vary = DC, huge = ton, laundromats = washing

...are all the small mountains lent out from other places?

> Hillsboro, OR
>  small mountains = hills, lent = borrow (borough)

...is every day the Fourth of July?

> Independence, MO
>  July 4th = American Independence Day

...is everyone always getting more of something?

> Gainesville, FL
>  more = gains

...is the fourteenth letter always really nervous?

> Cheyenne, WY (Thanks, [chrylis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33062/20151)!)
>  Cheyenne = shy N

...do all the people like to make scenes of themselves in their state's Capitol building, or at least sorta sound like they do?

> Austin, TX
>  Austin, Texas sounds like ostentatious which means to make a scene of oneself

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with [Matt's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33050/13535) except the following changes.

...is everyone a young male?

> Boise, Idaho

...do all the people like to make scenes of themselves in their state's Capitol building, or at least sorta sound like they do?

> This one seems like it should be a [state capital](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_capitals) based on the "state's Capitol building" part.
>  I'm guessing Little Rock, Arkansas (where Rock is a type of sound and rock musicians tend to make scenes at their concerts; Little goes with "sort of"; "arcane saws" are also noisy).

Comment: It is a state capital, but I'll give you a hint: the pun involves the city _and_ state name.

Answer (score 3):

[Matt has the first seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33050/18891), but for the others:

...is everyone always getting more of something?

> Increase, Mississippi is too small, but
>  everyone's being assigned Newark (new work) in New Jersey

...is the fourteenth letter always really nervous?

> Cheyenne (shy N), Wyoming!

Comment: Cheyenne is the correct answer for a different one.

Comment: There you go, you got it!

Comment: Although Increase, Mississippi is way to small. As I mentioned, all the towns I'm thinking of have a population of at least 50,000.

Comment: @JoeZ. Hmm. Industry, CA, has almost no residents...