# Which US city is it?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, geography, metapuzzles

*This is a more advanced punzzle with a first level based on the same concept as [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33047/13535).  Each of the questions below is answered by the name of a US city which could be pronounced in a way that has a pun relationship with the question.  These questions do not generally make use of the literal name in English or other languages (e.g. you won’t find a pair like …do they have a large population of heavenly beings / Los Angeles) so some creativity is required; a round of Mad Gab might be a good warmup.*

*Any close-to-reasonable pronunciation one could get out of the spelling of the name is fair game.   It might help to think of how English language learners (who incidentally  have an SE [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)) might try to pronounce the city name.  (This means that puns on the correct pronunciations of places like Worcester are out).*

*The answers to those questions then provide input to the sequence of strange events and question that follows.  The overall punzzle seeks the identification of a **single city** as the solution.  Of course, please share your intermediate steps.*

---

I started out looking for some cities, wondering in which one...

1. …are they never buyin’ things?
2. …do small sets of connected computers make music?
3. …do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear?
4. …do people give negative answers all over again?
5. …do people have overproductive livers?
6. …did they have to dig deep to find water?
7. …would you find yourself at the center of a river crossing?
8. …would you find your Wine house?
9. …would someone give a terse response to a Question of Scruples?
10. …would you find the Scottish girl?
11. …do people take a vendor’s unique perspective on “take ‘em or leave ‘em” situations?
12. …do they make cloths to protect relatively large passenger vehicles?
13. …would you find a comedy crew practicing on the river?
14. …do they add font weight?
15. …is it impossible to make ice?

After finding these cities, I wanted to ZIP up to City Hall, where I might find the mayor, but I lost the first number.
So I had to go around a lot of times and make a letter instead.
Unfortunately, I tripped, and everything got jumbled up.
When I brushed off the mud, I found two animals.
The leathery one moved away, and the sly one asked me where I might find results of the process of formation of the only thing that still remained.
It was very hard, and I hadn't yet thought of the answer.
**Where is it?**

---

Here's a constraint that might help if you get stuck:

> All cities have population >100K.

User [ev3commander](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17008/ev3commander) adds the following resource to make things easier than the constraint alone:

> [List of cities with population >100k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population)

Here's a hint if needed:

> It is significant that at least one clue in the list is missing punctuation, where it might otherwise go.

Folks on [The Great Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help on #3.  Their chat is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp).

As a bit of a hint for #3,

> Both the city and the pun are titles of (different) Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you would like to see a layer of complexity added to the puzzle (which would not invalidate any progress toward solving it as it currently stands).

Comment: 8 and 13 are probably the hardest.

Comment: I wonder if there should be a community wiki for this one, since the solutions are spread out in several answers

Comment: With sufficient interest, this puzzle has **leveled up.**  The hardest part of what's left relies on 3 and 13 as some extra incentive to get those.  Good luck, and enjoy!

Comment: @WBT Like the leveling up. Would it be too much of a hint to tell us whether we're looking for a *specific* comedy crew (e.g. SNL) or a general comedy crew (e.g. troupe, duo, ...)?

Comment: Leathery-> cow? sly->fox?

Comment: @ev3commander It is; Aggie Kidd got it.  Those in MA and other states fail the constraint, but the pun part still works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Collecting others' answers to the original clues so everything's in one spot.

1 …are they never buyin’ things?

> **Renton**, WA: They're always "rentin'" rather than "buyin'." ([From AggieKidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33162/13535))

2 …do small sets of connected computers make music?

> **Lansing**, MI: [Local Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) + sing

3 …do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear?

> <strike>**Charlotte**, NC (a lot of charcoal, probably wrong...verified incorrect)</strike>
>  <strike>**Nashville**, TN (There's a company called [Nash](http://www.nashmfg.com/sub-z/) that makes backpacking coolers...? Verified incorrect.)</strike>
>  <strike>**Berkeley**, CA (They have a lot of Kelley Kettles?)</strike> or
>  <strike>**Killeen**, TX (They have a lot of Kelley Kettles?)</strike> or
>  <strike>**Gilbert**, AZ (They have a lot of Ghillie Kettles?)</strike>
>  Soon we'll have guessed all 300 or so cities!
>  **Mesquite**, TX: "[Mess kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mess_kit)"  (explanation from [Brad Sandman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36555/13535))

4 ...do people give negative answers all over again?

> **Reno**, NV: "re-" meaning to do again, plus "no" ([From Joe Z.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33136/13535))

5 …do people have overproductive livers?

> **Mobile**, AL: mo' [bile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bile)

6 ...did they have to dig deep to find water?

> **Lowell**, MA: a "low well" ([From Joe Z.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33136/13535))

7 …would you find yourself at the center of a river crossing?

> **Hartford**, CT: heart, aka center, of the [ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_(crossing))

8  …would you find your Wine house?

> **Miami**, FL: My [Amy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2870648/) [Winehouse] ([From ColleenV](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33169/13535))

9 ...would someone give a terse response to a Question of Scruples?

> **Plano**, TX: in [Scruples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scruples_(game)), "no" is the shortest (most terse) answer on a card. You'd "play no" on the question somebody is asking you. ([From Joe Z.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33136/13535))

10 …would you find the Scottish girl?

> **Dallas**, TX: In Scotland, a [girl](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lass) is often called a "[lass](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lass), so we have "da lass."  ([From AggieKidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33162/13535))

11 …do people take a vendor’s unique perspective on “take ‘em or leave ‘em” situations?

> **Salem**, OR: Vendors don't "take 'em" or "leave 'em", they "sale 'em"  ([From AggieKidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33162/13535))

12 ...do they make cloths to protect relatively large passenger vehicles?

> **Vancouver**, WA: "van cover" ([From Joe Z.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33136/13535))

13 …would you find a comedy crew practicing on the river?

> **Rochester**, NY: "row jester"

14 …do they add font weight?

> **Boulder**, CO: "bolder"

15 …is it impossible to make ice?

> **Fresno**, CA: "freeze no"

---

### Meta puzzle

After finding these cities, I wanted to ZIP up to City Hall, where I might find the mayor, but I lost the first number.  So I had to go around a lot of times and make a letter instead.

> I think this means to take the ZIP code of City Hall in each of the cities, then drop the first number from each.  After that, go around and around (mod 26) and convert the result to a letter.
>
>  98057 → 8057, 8057 mod 26 = 23 → **W**
>  48933 → 8933, 8933 mod 26 = 15 → **O**
>  75149 → 5149, 5149 mod 26 = 1 → **A**
>  89505 → 9505, 9505 mod 26 = 15 → **O**
>  36602 → 6602, 6602 mod 26 = 24 → **X**
>  01852 → 1852, 1852 mod 26 = 6 → **F**
>  06103 → 6103, 6103 mod 26 = 19 → **S**
>  33133 → 3133, 3133 mod 26 = 13 → **M**
>  75074 → 5074, 5074 mod 26 = 4 → **D**
>  75201 → 5201, 5201 mod 26 = 1 → **A**
>  97301 → 7301, 7301 mod 26 = 21 → **U**
>  98660 → 8660, 8660 mod 26 = 2 → **B**
>  14614 → 4614, 4614 mod 26 = 12 → **L**
>  <s>80302 → 0302, 0302 mod 26 = 16 → **P**</s>
>  80306 → 0306, 0306 mod 26 = 20 → **T**
>  93721 → 3721, 3721 mod 26 = 3 → **C**

Unfortunately, I tripped, and everything got jumbled up.

> WOAOXFSMDAUBLTC

When I brushed off the mud,

> WOAOXFSMDAUBLTC - MUD = WOAOXFSABLTC

I found two animals.

> **FOX** and **COW**, leaving ASABLT

The leathery one moved away, and the sly one asked me where I might find results of the process of formation of the only thing that still remained.

> Process of formation of **BASALT**

It was very hard, and I hadn't yet thought of the answer.

> **[BASALT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt)** *is* hard.  The word even [derives](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=basalt) from Latin for "very hard stone."

Where is it?

> <s>Not sure yet.  If the "B" is somehow an "M", it could be PLASMA, which of course is made in **Sunnyvale**, CA</s>
>
>  <s>Perhaps in **Basalt**, Colorado?  Or in **Hilo**, Hawaii?</s>
>
>  <s>**Rockford**, IL or **Round Rock**, TX or **Little Rock**, AK?</s>
>
>  <s>**Las Vegas**, NV (Lava gas)?</s>
>
>  [Thanks to @MatthewGreen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33133/which-us-city-is-it/33137?noredirect=1#comment111195_33137):
>  **Charlotte**, NC: a char[red] lot, because basalt is formed from cooling lava, so after a lava flow you're likely going to have a lot of charred material on what would then be a "char lot."

Comment: Five for five!  Keep on going!

Comment: CONGRATS!  You got #13!

Comment: #3 is still up for grabs.  Does the extra hint help?  Once you open the pun article, it'll be pretty obvious that's the right one.

Comment: @WBT So definitely not [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Kettle), huh? Seemed promising.

Comment: It was a great guess, but there's a better fit out there.  It's fairly direct and not subtle.

Comment: Nice progress! That wasn't the intended explanation on #3, though, and it looks like you've got the mayor's home address instead of her work address for 14.

Comment: You're getting warmer with the latter guess, conceptually speaking.  What is the process of formation of that hard thing?  (Also, check out the etymology to help improve that part of the answer.)

Comment: Mobile -> mo bile -> more bile.

Comment: @WBT So I've got the right hard thing (BASALT)? And the answer to the whole puzzle is another city > 100000 population? And it's a clue like the others, but it's where the aforementioned thing is formed? And the etymology clue is about the hard thing?

Comment: Basically yes, though the description/reasoning could be improved.  
16: ...where I might find results of the process of formation of basalt?

Comment: @WBT Round Rock, TX? Little Rock, AK? Rockford, IL? The way that's worded, it seems like the "results of the process of formation of basalt" would be...basalt.

Comment: @DanRussell think about other/side effects.  How is basalt formed?

Comment: It's formed by rapid cooling of exposed lava in air or water. So other results might include e.g. lava flows. I had a look down that list of city names and didn't see anything that (to me) looked like it had that sort of significance. (Round Rock and Little Rock are indeed named after rocks but they don't appear to have that origin. Boulder, CO is named after Boulder Creek.) Do we need to look up information about every city in the US until we find one with a famous lava flow or similar?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Note that the puzzle's gimmick is *not* taking the city names literally. So the correct answer will likely be some sort of misreading/pun related to the process of formation of basalt. Other words and/or potential by-products I've tried to find in the city list: erupt(ion), steam, island, lava, ash, rock. Mostly without success.

Comment: Boise? If the lava flow is underwater, it will boil the sea.

Comment: Lava flow is the correct process (or part thereof) to have in mind. "Lava gas" and "boil sea" are two reasonable answers, but there's one out there that's a better fit (also with the spelling of the city name). Reframing hint: *16: ...where I might find the results of extremely hot material flowing over an area of land?*

Comment: @WBT what about a charred lot (Charlotte, NC)?

Comment: @MatthewGreen There you go!  Congrats!

Comment: @WBT I tried to tidy everything up. Finally done?!

Comment: [Brad did get the ZIP code correction](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/36555/5) before [you did](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/33137/14) - and without the explanation, your getting the right city on #3 was a lucky guess.

Comment: @WBT My only point was that I didn't see Brad's answer until after I'd added both Mesquite and changed the ZIP code. (No way you could know that, but it's true.)  I only changed the zip code to make the answer = Basalt, not because I really found a good reason (via GoogleMaps) that is should be ---06 instead of ---02. Even the [Municipal building itself](https://bouldercolorado.gov/city-council) has ---02, it's just the PO Box I think that has ---06. In any event, thanks for a nice puzzle that took a lot of my time to finally put to rest!  Working on a sequel?

Comment: @DanRussell thinking about it, but there won't be any real soon.  I'm also still thinking about if the next one will go on this site or to the [MIT Mystery Hunt](http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/).  I'm glad you enjoyed this one!

Comment: @WBT Cool. Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 8):

3 ...do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear?

> **Hollywood**, FL — they're "wholly wood".

4 ...do people give negative answers all over again?

> **Reno**, NV — "re-" meaning to do again, plus "no"

6 ...did they have to dig deep to find water?

> **Lowell**, MA — a "low well"

9 ...would someone give a terse response to a Question of Scruples?

> **Plano**, TX — in Scruples, "no" is the shortest (most terse) answer on a card. You'd "play no" on the question somebody is asking you.

11 ...do people take a vendor’s unique perspective on “take ‘em or leave ‘em” situations?

> **Salem**, MA — instead of "take 'em" or "leave 'em", you "sale 'em"

12 ...do they make cloths to protect relatively large passenger vehicles?

> **Vancouver**, WA — they make "van covers"

Comment: Oh, I get it now.

Comment: I actually was thinking of "Vancouver" for my "Canadian pun city" problem, so that's how I got that one. :P

Comment: "Ontario, CA" was definitely a better answer for that one.

Comment: No, I mean, I'm making a new question consisting of Canadian cities rather than US ones, and I used the exact same pun you did except with Vancouver, BC instead (which has a lot more people in it).

Comment: Good try on #3, but not it.

Answer (score 6):

A few of my additions:

1 …are they never buyin’ things?

> **Renton**, WA, "Rentin'" They're just "rentin'" rather than "buyin'".

3  …do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear?

> **Albuquerque**, NM, *Al-Baq-Querqe* $\rightarrow$ *Out - Back - Cookery*  - Confirmed incorrect.

7 …would you find yourself at the center of a river crossing?

> **Hartford**, CT, "Heart Ford", the heart or middle of a ford.

10 …would you find the Scottish girl?

> **Dallas**, TX, "Da-Las", A Scottish girl is often called a "lass", so we have "da Lass".

11 …do people take a vendor’s unique perspective on “take ‘em or leave ‘em” situations?

> **Salem**, OR, "Sale - Em", Vendors don't "take 'em" or "leave 'em", they "sale 'em"

Comment: Good guess on the latest, but there's a better answer out there; you'll recognize the answer when you get it.  I generally avoided using the intended meanings of city names in this puzzle.

Comment: JoeZ has the intended explanation for 11.  Of the others: One has the right city but a slightly better explanation exists; two are wrong. Those that remain are fully correct (though one could contest some spelling).

Comment: For your (current) answer for #1, if it's right - I'd say the explanation would have to do with ----in', similar to the buyin'

Comment: It's no longer a shot in the dark, but still just as far off.

Comment: It's less of a stretch than that.

Comment: @AggieKidd My god, the number of different ways I've tried to pronounce Albuquerque because of this puzzle...

Comment: @DanRussell The number of ways I've tried pronouncing a lot of these. Baton Rouge, every ...ville...

Answer (score 5):

A guess for number 8

8  …would you find your Wine house?

> Miami, FL My (mi) Amy (ami) Winehouse (Wine house) Nice clue capitalizing Wine!

Comment: Nice work!  +1 for number solved.

Comment: I was looking for something that was "amy" D:

Comment: @JoeZ. I approached it from the "my/mi" (since it was 'your house')

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily expecting either of these to be right (both are a bit of a stretch), but I figured I'd keep the ball rolling on this.

3 …do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear?

> **Rancho Cucamonga**, CA ("Ranch o' cook mongers")

13 …would you find a comedy crew practicing on the river?

> **Cambridge**, MA ("Com-bridge")

Comment: Nice try, but no hits.  Keep thinking anyway!

Answer (score 1):

(continuing from Dan Russell)

#3  …do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear?

> Bakersfield, CA, 93301, 3301 % 26 = 25 -> Y (confirmed INCORRECT)

Instead...

> Oh, Mesquite, TX is correct, but it's because it means "Mess Kit"

Leaving

> ASYBLP -> "BY ALPS" (INCORRECT)

ZIP to City Hall

> https://bouldercolorado.gov/city-council/council-member-suzanne-jones shows Municipal Bldg at 80306 ... 0306 % 26 = 20 -> T

...where I might find results of the process of formation of the only thing that still remained.

> COW FOX ASABLT -> "BASALT"

It was very hard, and I hadn't yet thought of the answer.

> Gotthard Pass (INCORRECT)

Where am I?

> Switzerland, South Carolina? Or, the closest "big city," Savannah, GA? (INCORRECT)

Comment: Interesting guesses, but not correct!  [Aggie Kidd also guessed that on #3](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/33162/7), but later edited it out (and I wouldn't expect you to check other answers like that; it's fun to figure these out on one's own).

Comment: I think I understand #3 now, but that leaves me stumped on the final puzzle.

Comment: What is the process of formation of that thing that remains?  Also, consider linking the Wikipedia article to help improve the major advance you made near the top of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A guess

13…would you find a comedy crew practicing on the river?

> Lafayette, LA      Laf = Laugh   ...   **confirmed Incorrect**

Answer (score 0):

3. do they have a good supply of backcountry cooking gear? 
   Maybe...

   > Greeley, Colorado
   >  Sounds like "grill" (Confirmed wrong)

Comment: Nope, more backcountry than backyard.

Answer (score 0):

13. would you find a comedy crew practicing on the river?

Wild guess:

> Rockford, IL 
>  "rocking on the ford" (wrong)

Comment: Nope.  This one has nothing to do with the actual meaning of any part of the city name ("ford," "bank," "bridge," "rio," etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I checked my answers against others posted when I couldn't figure out the meta question. I got most of them right, a few wrong. Looks like the only one that a correct answer hasn't been found for is #3, so here's the only guess I had that hasn't been posted yet:

> Stockton, CA (stock has been used in cooking for ages, back country or not, and they have a "ton" of it here)

Comment: Nice guess.  #3 did have a correct answer posted, by Brad Sandman, which is also now incorporated into Dan Russell's answer.  You can check there or you can keep guessing without checking yourself, for the fun of it.